# Markdown list inside a table

Tags: html, markdown

As per title,

Is it possible to put a list inside a table in markdown?

I tried to search it up but could not find anything.

A Table being something like:

```
Fruit    |Color
---------|----------
Apples   |Red
Pears    |Green
```

and a list being something like

- List item 1
- List item 2

Comment: That does not explain how to put a list inside a table

Comment: There are several different types of **Markdown** (like GitHub Flavored Markdown) each having its own customization to the original one from _Daring Fireball_. [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=custom+markdown+syntax) and have a look which one suits your needs. If you can't find it, then it might not be possible yet. _Try to create a custom version yourself_ and utilize that. This is how the other versions were created. They also needed "custom" functionality on top of the existing Markdown tool.

Comment: Reason why I posted this was because I did a good amount of googling and nothing came up.. Assuming then that such a customization has not yet been created

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write lists inside a markdown table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950648/how-to-write-lists-inside-a-markdown-table)

Answer (score 10):

You can [combine HTML inside Markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#wiki-html) to create the list, like so:

```
Version | Name | Features
-------:|------|----------
1.0     |Alpha |<ul><li>Supports</li><li>lists</li><li>with HTML</li></ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to create a list (unorganzied) inside a table. in order to that you need to create a table, and create a unorganazied list within it.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Fruits</td>
<td>Colors</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <ul>
        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Pears</li>
    </ul>
</td>
<td>
    <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Green</li>
    </ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is ofcourse an inapropriate explanation, I would reccomend learning properly (I really like [codeacademy).](http://www.codecademy.com/)

Good luck :)