# How to write lists inside a markdown table?

Tags: html, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Can one create a list (bullets, numbered or not) inside a markdown table.

A table looks like this:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

A list looks like this:

```
* one
* two
* three
```

Can I merge them somehow?

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Yes, you can merge them using HTML. When I create tables in `.md` files from Github, I always like to use HTML code instead of markdown.

[Github Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) supports basic HTML in `.md` file. So this would be the answer:

Markdown mixed with HTML:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
| <ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li></ul>| See the list | from the first column|
```

Or pure HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Tables</th>
      <th align="center">Are</th>
      <th align="right">Cool</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 3 is</td>
      <td align="center">right-aligned</td>
      <td align="right">$1600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 2 is</td>
      <td align="center">centered</td>
      <td align="right">$12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>zebra stripes</td>
      <td align="center">are neat</td>
      <td align="right">$1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item2</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td align="center">See the list</td>
      <td align="right">from the first column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how it looks on Github:

> [image]

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to style the list too? Remove bullets, margins, etc.? Github, for example, doesn't seem to accept a `style="list-style: none"` tag on the `ul` element.

Comment: @TreborRude No, because Markdown is not HTML actually. But if you use a library (e.g. [`marked`](https://github.com/chjj/marked)), you probably have this feature (to combine HTML with markdown).

Comment: It's ok, I found out that a `<span>` tag with embedded `<br/>` tags did exactly what I was trying to do with the styled list.

Comment: @TreborRude Sure, you still can have multiple line cells. Probably it accepts `<p>` tags as well.

Comment: I'm happy to confirm that the first one (embedded `<ul><li>foo</li></ul>`) also works on Bitbucket Server.

Comment: Use `ol` if you need ordered lists. Example `<ol><li>Enumeration 1<li><li>Enumeration 2</li></ol>`.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. And it stays with Markdown instead of adding extraneous stuff to solve a simple problem.

Comment: not sure but can this be done in rmarkdown?

Answer (score 120):

If you want a no-bullet list (or any other non-standard usage) or more lines in a cell use `<br />`

```
| Event         | Platform      | Description |
| ------------- |-----------| -----:|
| `message_received`| `facebook-messenger`<br/>`skype`|
```

Comment: Probably because three years ago it was the only reasonable answer? I agree with you that this is a better answer, today.

Comment: This is an answer to [Newline in markdown table?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11700487/1048572), not this question about lists

Comment: @Bergi I've upvoted your suggestion. ;) The google search led me to this question and this the solution I needed. I think it's bearable (e.g. non-bulleted list) so I keep it at this very place.

Comment: You can add bullets with HTML entities: &bull; `facebook-messenger`<br/>&bull; `skype`

Comment: markdown lint flags this as [no inline html](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/v0.8.1/doc/Rules.md#md033)

Answer (score 60):

Not that I know of, because all markdown references I am aware of, [like this one](http://etherealmind.com/who-am-i/markdown-reference/), mention:

> **Cell content must be on one line only**

You can try it with that [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) (whose example looks like the one you mention in your question, so you may be aware of it already).

## Pandoc

If you are using [Pandoc’s markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html) (which *extends*  [John Gruber’s markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) on which the [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) is based) you can use either [`grid_tables`](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-grid_tables):

> ```
> +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
> | Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
> +===============+===============+====================+
> | Bananas       | $1.34         | - built-in wrapper |
> |               |               | - bright color     |
> +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
> | Oranges       | $2.10         | - cures scurvy     |
> |               |               | - tasty            |
> +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
> ```

or [`multiline_tables`](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-multiline_tables).

> ```
> -------------------------------------------------------------
>  Centered   Default           Right Left
>   Header    Aligned         Aligned Aligned
> ----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
>    First    row                12.0 Example of a row that
>                                     spans multiple lines.
>
>   Second    row                 5.0 Here's another one. Note
>                                     the blank line between
>                                     rows.
> -------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Comment: The Markdown Tables Generator is wrong because it accepts new lines that, as you quote, are not accepted. But thanks for the valuable information.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay The Markdown Tables Generator being a relatively new service, I am not surprised ;) But regarding "GitHub Flavored Markdown", my answer stands.

Comment: I tend to accept your answer. But I wait 1-2 days more, maybe someone posts a hack (if answer accepted, no one will look at it, except others with the same problem)

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay I agree. You also can contact GitHub support, and see what they have to say about it. (and then update my answer or post your own)

Comment: Done! Also instructed them to reply here :) with a comment or a new answer.

Comment: @イオニカビザウ I obviously didn't mentioned HTML. With HTML, you can recreate any markdown feature, so it is *not* a valid solution. The question is about markdown, *not* HTML.

Comment: @VonC I saw that is tagged as `github-flavored-markdown`. Github Flavored markdown supports HTML.

Comment: @VonC if I use your `grid_tables` code in an Rmd file and use knitr to generate PDF output, the table contains a blank line after each list for some reason. Any idea why this is the case or how to circumvent this (pandoc) behavior?

Comment: @mavericks 7 years later.... no precise idea, really: try and ask a separate question, with illustration of the bug.

Comment: This works well with [Quarto tables](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/tables.html) and its cross-reference mechanism

Answer (score 12):

another solution , you can add `<br>` tag to your table

```
    |Method name| Behavior |
    |--|--|
    | OnAwakeLogicController(); | Its called when MainLogicController is loaded into the memory , its also hold the following actions :- <br> 1. Checking Audio Settings <br>2. Initializing Level Controller|
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach, which I've recently implemented, is to use the [div-table plugin](https://github.com/sergiocorreia/panflute-filters/blob/master/filters/div-tables.py) with [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/).

This creates a table from a set of fenced divs (standard in the [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans) implementation of markdown), in a similar layout to html:

```
---
panflute-filters: [div-table]
panflute-path: 'panflute/docs/source'
---

::::: {.divtable}
:::: {.tcaption}
a caption here (optional), only the first paragraph is used.
::::
:::: {.thead}
[Header 1]{width=0.4 align=center}
[Header 2]{width=0.6 align=default}
::::
:::: {.trow}
::: {.tcell}

1. any
2. normal markdown
3. can go in a cell

:::
::: {.tcell}
![](https://pixabay.com/get/e832b60e2cf7043ed1584d05fb0938c9bd22ffd41cb2144894f9c57aae/bird-1771435_1280.png?attachment){width=50%}

some text
:::
::::
:::: {.trow bypara=true}
If bypara=true

Then each paragraph will be treated as a separate column
::::
any text outside a div will be ignored
:::::
```

Looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using Kramdown (the default Markdown renderer for [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/)) then you have to use the [nomarkdown extension](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#extensions) `{::nomarkdown}...{:/}`.

For example:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| {::nomarkdown}<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul>{:/} | Kramdown | bullets |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the html approach:

**don't add blank lines**

Like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

the markup will break.

Remove blank lines:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: HTML will ignore blank lines and multiple whitespaces, so I don't see any problems with that. Could you explain what will break here?

Answer (score 1):

For [Python markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/), I recommend using the [GridTables](https://github.com/bmocm/Markdown-GridTables) markdown extension. In particular, the forked version I linked has worked best for me with mkdocs-material, and it supports lists and most markdown formatting. Multiline code blocks will not render well.

Comment: How did you install it for mkdocs? I don't see it in the default extension lists: https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/extensions/python-markdown/

Answer (score 0):

One solution that hasn't been shown:

- create the table using html `<table>` tag
- write markdown inside *table cells*

Works by adding a newline after `<td>`:

````
<table><tbody>
<tr>
  <th> Left column </th>
  <th> Right column </th>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>

  * Just `write` **markdown**
  * In _here_
  </td>
  <td>

  ```python
  def or_here():
    pass
  ```
  </td>
<tbody></table>
````

Looks like this:

[image]

How to:

- add an empty newline after `<td>`
- the "zero-indent" indentation is on the level as the `<td>`

It's a little finicky to get right but is nicer than writing full-blown html.