# How to link in markdown from an inline code fragment?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is there a way to link form inside a code fragment in the Github markdown?

For example: `` `I want THIS to be a link` `` where `THIS` looks like [`THIS`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19950648/454103).

Comment: When linking in run-of-the-mill markdown you would write: "I want [\*THIS\*](www.example.com) to be a link"  Is that what you are referring to? If not, you should be more explicit in your question.

Comment: Nope. I want: `to write a LINK HERE inside this code fragment`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it's not possible via markdown, but if the markdown interpreter accepts HTML code you can do: `<code>I want <a href="...">THIS</a> to be a link</code>`.

Here is how it looks (rendered): `chromium-browser https://stackoverflow.com/`

And, yes! Github allows HTML code in the markdown files. Here is a screen shot from a gist with the code above:

> [image]