# how do I insert new line in a gitlab wiki markdown table cell

Tags: markdown, gitlab

I am trying insert a table in gitlab wiki page. Is there a way to insert new line in a table cell?

I tried the following and it didn't work.

```
| Tables        | Are                     | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-----------------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned <br> test | $1600 |
```

Comment: Since GitLab 14.3 (Sept. 2021), this is now easier: see [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21682637/6309)

Answer (score 7):

Update Sept. 2021:

See [GitLab 14.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#edit-a-tables-structure-visually-in-the-new-wiki-editor) (September 2021)

> ### Edit a table’s structure visually in the new wiki editor
>
> Edit a table’s structure visually in the new wiki editor
>
> Editing a Markdown table that has 9 columns and 25 rows is one thing. But adding a tenth column to that table in Markdown? That involves very repetitive and error-prone edits to every row. One mistake or misplaced `|` and the table fails to render.
>
> The new WYSIWYG Markdown editor in the wiki lets you quickly and easily insert a table using the button in the toolbar. After selecting the initial number of rows and columns, however, dealing with the structure of the table can be more difficult. In GitLab 14.3, you can now click on the caret icon in the top right corner of any selected cell to add or remove columns and rows, either before or after the selected cell. Now, as your content scales, the complexity doesn’t follow suit.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_3/wiki-editor-edit-table-structure.png -- Edit a table's structure visually in the new wiki editor]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/#content-editor) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/328759).

---

Original answer 2014: Table markdown has been introduced in GitLab with [commit 0093554a](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/0093554ad6055a0843b0537557e8ca44d6ff2429), which includes:

> Tables aren't part of the core Markdown spec, but they are part of GFM and Markdown Here supports them.

And GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown) doesn't directly support newlines in a cell for [GFM Tables](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#wiki-tables).
You can try html code as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976953/6309), but that what your question illustrates (although I would I tried other well-formatted html element, like `<br />`, as in "[Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/6309)").

Comment: `<br>` is well-formed HTML. The slash is only required in XML, and in fact changes the semantics in HTML4. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/354577

Comment: @Chris Ok. I have added that link to the answer.

Answer (score -3):

Well, if you really like the feature you want, you can write your own parser. For example, GFM doesn't support footnotes, then you can update the parser to support footnotes.