# Lists in markdown table (with Jekyll)

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I'm writing document with Jekyll/Markdown and its engine is kramdown.
And now I'm wondering the way to write lists in table built by markdown.

I tried following.

```
|Name   |Columns             |
|-------|--------------------|
|PRIMARY|<ul><li>id</li></ul>|
```

In GitHub's Gist, it's rendered as I thought.

But in Jekyll (my local one or GitHub Pages' one), it's not.
http://yuya-takeyama.github.io/2011/10/08/hello-github-pages.html

Is there any way to write lists in table in Jekyll?
I'll replace markdown engine if it's required.

Answer (score 10):

[nomarkdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#extensions) tag helps:

```
|Name   |Columns                               |
|-------|--------------------------------------|
|PRIMARY|{::nomarkdown}<ul><li>id</li></ul>{:/}|
```

[image: Jekyll rendered table]

The solution works with both kramdown and redcarpet.

Answer (score 3):

As we known, Jekyll uses kramdown as a default markdown converter from 2.0+. And It doesn't support the table cell **alignment**, **merging** and so on, I think the below can help you.

> jekyll-spaceship -  *A Jekyll plugin to provide powerful supports for
> table, mathjax, plantuml, mermaid, emoji, video, youtube, vimeo, dailymotion, etc.*

https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship

> **For now, these extended features are provided:**
>
> - Cells spanning multiple columns
> - Cells spanning multiple rows
> - Cells text align separately
> - Table header not required
> - Grouped table header rows or data rows

Markdown:

[image: table code]

Code above would be parsed as:

[image: html table]

Answer (score 2):

I [think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950648/how-to-write-lists-inside-a-markdown-table) Kramdown doesn't [support multiline tables](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#tables), and no HTML in table cells either (although I'm no Kramdown expert).

However, Pandoc has a few different [table syntaxes](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#tables), among them:

```
+---------+----------+
| Name    | Columns  |
+=========+==========+
| PRIMARY | - id one |
|         | - id two |
+---------+----------+
```

You can use, [this plugin](https://github.com/fauno/jekyll-pandoc-multiple-formats) to use Pandoc from Jekyll. Note, that you'll have to run Jekyll locally since GitHub doesn't support Jekyll plugins.

Comment: I tested the table by Yuya with my settings and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to maximize GitHub Markdown compatibility:

```
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
  extensions:
    - no_intra_emphasis
    - fenced_code_blocks
    - autolink
    - tables
    - strikethrough
    - superscript
    - with_to_data
```

The extension addressing your question is `tables`, but you probably want the rest if you want your Gists to look like your pages for the same markup.

Comment: Unfortunately, GitHub Pages doesn't support *redcarpet* anymore, so you have to build the Jekyll Pages by yourself for this solution.

Answer (score -3):

1. Open `_config.yml`
2. Add `markdown: kramdown`
3. Run `jekyll serve` in your terminal.
4. Enjoy.

Please check out the kramdown manual for more information about how to pimp your tables: http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#tables

Comment: This does not work. kramdown renders all elements outside of a table. But HTML lists inside a markdown table are not rendered.

Comment: That answer do not have a relationship to the question "multiline / lists inside a table"