# Adding a list and nested table inside a markdown table

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to add:

- a bulleted list
- a table inside a cell

inside a table. Basically it is a nested table.
It is a markdown file.
Can you tell me how to do it?

I want to add:

- a bulleted list
- a table inside a cell

inside a table. Basically it is a nested table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write lists inside a markdown table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950648/how-to-write-lists-inside-a-markdown-table)